# I want to know why this result is output

Tags: c, linux, gcc

##### source code

```
/***************************************************
 * Copyright: 2023, 黄子涵.
 * File name: huangzihan_c_program_142
 * Description: 改变指针的值
 * Author: 黄子涵
 * Version: V1.0.0
 * Date: 2023-01-08
 * ****************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>

char huangzihan[10];
char huangchunqin[12];
char chenlanying[12];
char shejiazi[8];
void name_input();
void name_output();
void name_output_n();

void name_input()
{
    int i;
    printf("*********************************\n");
    printf("     给字符数组输入对应的名字    \n");
    printf("*********************************\n");
    printf("请输入黄子涵的小写拼音：");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &huangzihan[i]);
        if (huangzihan[i] == 10)
        {
            huangzihan[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    getchar();
    printf("请输入黄春钦的小写拼音：");
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &huangchunqin[i]);
        if (huangchunqin[i] == 10)
        {
            huangchunqin[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    getchar();
    printf("请输入陈兰英的小写拼音：");
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &chenlanying[i]);
        if (chenlanying[i] == 10)
        {
            chenlanying[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    getchar();
    printf("请输入佘佳梓的小写拼音：");
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &shejiazi[i]);
        if (shejiazi[i] == 10)
        {
            shejiazi[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void name_output()
{
    char *p1,*p2,*p3,*p4;
    printf("*********************************\n");
    printf("     将字符数组对应的名字输出    \n");
    printf("*********************************\n");
    printf("输出huangzihan：");
    p1 = huangzihan;
    printf("%s", p1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("输出huangchunqin：");
    p2 = huangchunqin;
    printf("%s", p2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("输出chenlanying：");
    p3 = chenlanying;
    printf("%s", p3);
    printf("\n");
    printf("输出shejiazi：");
    p4 = shejiazi;
    printf("%s", p4);
    printf("\n");
}

void name_output_n()
{
    int i;
    char *p;
    printf("\n");
    printf("*********************************\n");
    printf("           改变指针的值          \n");
    printf("*********************************\n");
    printf("你要从第几个字符输出huangzihan（共10个字符）？");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p = huangzihan + i - 1;
    printf("这是你要输出的字符串：%s", p);
    printf("\n");
    printf("你要从第几个字符输出huangchunqin（共12个字符）？");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p = huangchunqin + i - 1;
    printf("这是你要输出的字符串：%s", p);
    printf("\n");
    printf("你要从第几个输出chenlanying（共11个字符）？");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p = chenlanying + i - 1;
    printf("这是你要输出的字符串：%s", p);
    printf("\n");
    printf("你要从第几个输出shejiazi（共8个字符）？");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    p = shejiazi + i - 1;
    printf("这是你要输出的字符串：%s", p);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    extern char huangzihan[10];
    extern char huangchunqin[12];
    extern char chenlanying[12];
    extern char shejiazi[8];
    name_input();
    name_output();
    name_output_n();
    return 0;
}
```

At first, I thought it was the problem of not adding the end tag of the string, but I added the end tag of the string and found it didn't work.Add code as follows：

```
    if (shejiazi[i] == 10) {
        shejiazi[i] = '\0';
        break;
    }
```

##### I want to output results

```
输出huangzihan：huangzihan
输出huangchunqin：huangchunqin
输出chenlanying：chenlanying
输出shejiazi：shejiazi
```

##### Actual output results

[image: Actual output results]

I want to know why this happens. If you know, please tell me. Thank you very much。

Comment: do not change character of '10'. try *chenlanying`[i+1]`='\0';* instead.

Comment: I changed the number of elements in the array to 15, and there was no such problem.

Comment: Don't use global variables unless you have to.  What is the point of the extern variables in mail?  Use English otherwise most people will not be able to read it.  Use sizeof() instead of hard-coding magic value.  If you read 10 bytesin the array needs to be 11 bytes long for the trailing '\0'.  I am guessing the data is unicode?  Then it's less than characters .

Comment: Your code is very repetitive.  Why do you read characters %c instead of a string %c?

Comment: Post data here not links to external images.

Comment: By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). The copyright notice in the code is thus not really enforceable.

Comment: Next time, please try to simplify your code down to a [mcve] instead of providing very long and repetitive code, and write a title for your question that actually describes the problem.

Comment: This is an exercise on global variables in the textbook.@Allan Wind

Comment: I see. I will be sure next time@David Grayson

Comment: I didn't know how to copy the code in Bash at first, but now I know how to copy it.@ Allan Wind

Comment: This is what I habitually added during practice and copied it by the way during copying. It should not be a problem.@tripleee

Answer (score 2):

If the input string has exactly the maximum number of characters, the target array is not null terminated, causing `printf("...%s", ...)` to have undefined behavior. If your case it seems the arrays `huangchunqin` and `chenlanying` are adjacent in memory, so `printf("%s",p2);` outputs the contents of `huangchunqin` until it finds a null terminator, which does not occur before the end of `chenlanying`.

You should make the arrays one byte longer and use a function to read these strings:

```
/* Author: 查理戈登 */
/* Description: 程序的修改版本 */

#include <stdio.h>

char huangzihan[11];
char huangchunqin[13];
char chenlanying[13];
char shejiazi[9];

// read a string into a char array of a given length,
// return EOF if no input at end of file, 1 if truncated, 0 otherwise
int input_string(const char *prompt, char *dest, size_t size) {
    size_t i = 0;
    int c;
    int result = 0;

    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (i + 1 < size) {
            dest[i++] = c;
        } else {
            result = 1;
        }
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    if (i == 0 && c == EOF)
        result = EOF;
    return result;
}

void name_input(void) {
   printf("*********************************\n");
   printf("     给字符数组输入对应的名字    \n");
   printf("*********************************\n");
   // Qǐng shūrù shéjiāzǐ de xiǎoxiě pīnyīn
   input_string("请输入黄子涵的小写拼音", huangzihan, sizeof huangzihan);
   input_string("请输入黄春钦的小写拼音", huangchunqin, sizeof huangchunqin);
   input_string("请输入陈兰英的小写拼音", chenlanying, sizeof chenlanying);
   input_string("请输入佘佳梓的小写拼音", shejiazi, sizeof shejiazi);
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have learned the chapter of pointer now. For me, your method is relatively new.@查理戈登

Answer (score 0):

In `name_input()` you don't terminate your strings correctly as the last iteration is `i=9`:

```
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        scanf("%c",&huangzihan[i]);
        if(huangzihan[i]==10)
        {
            huangzihan[i]='\0';
            break;
        }
    }
```

Instead you could do:

```
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < sizeof huangzihan - 1; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &huangzihan[i]);
    }
    huangzihan[i] = '\0';
```

I don't know if your letters entered fit into the `char` if not you will get some weird corruption.

You can also just read a string with:

```
#define huangzihan_len 9
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s
char huangzihan[huangzihan_len+1];

//...

    scanf("%" str(huangzihan_len) "s", huangzihan);
```

After reading a string you do `getchar()` presumably to get rid of the newline.  You can change the format string with an initial space to do that automatically " %c", or make a flush function that discards all data till you hit a new line:

```
void flush() {
   for(;;) {
       int ch = getchar();
       if(ch == EOF || ch == '\n') return;
   }
}
```

Your code is repetitive so consider using an array to hold your strings, as they are different length perhaps an array of string pointers `char *str[4]`?